# Magento 2 admin Ajax call failed bad request

Tags: magento-2.1, magento2.3, adminhtml, ajax, admin-controller

I'm using custom js in Product Add/Edit page of magento 2 admin. I need to make a ajax call when the product save button clicked. I used the below code.

```
require(['jquery', 'domReady!'], function ($) {
    $(document).ajaxComplete(function () {
        let data = '';
        varr.forEach((i, j) => {
            if (i.length > 0) {
               data = JSON.stringify({
                  "data": {
                     "sku": sku,
                     "brand": i[0].brand,
                     "variant": i[0].variant,
                     "vehicle_type": "car",
                     "model": i[0].model
                  }
               });
            }

            var settings = {
               "async": true,
               "crossDomain": true,
               "url": "http://192.168.2.196/motogaadi/rest/V1/garage/garage_sku_insert/",
               "method": "POST",
               "headers": {
                 "Content-Type": "application/json",
                 "Cache-Control": "no-cache",
                 "cache-control": "no-cache"
               },
               "processData": false,
               "data": data
             }

             $.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
               console.log(response);
             });

      });
});

});
```

I am receiving the below issue.

`POST http://192.168.2.196/motogaadi/rest/V1/garage/garage_sku_insert/?isAjax=true 400 (Bad Request)`

The same Ajax call is working in frontend but not in adminhtml.

Comment: thanks but it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

In your ajax setting
modified like this:

```
    var settings = {
       "async": true,
       "crossDomain": true,
       "url": "http://192.168.2.196/motogaadi/rest/V1/garage/garage_sku_insert/",
       "method": "POST",
       "headers": {
         "Content-Type": "application/json",
         "Cache-Control": "no-cache",
         "cache-control": "no-cache"
       },
       "processData": false,
       "data": data,
       beforeSend: function (xhr) {
        //Empty to remove magento's default handler
    },
```

}

Comment: beforeSend option must be empty. This is important.